# How to contact multiple potential supervisors in the same lab?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, advisor, email

I am based in Europe and I want to start my PhD in a lab composed of several professors.

I would like to write to two of them to know if they are willing to accept new students and on which topic.

I have written a personalized email to the two professors, and I understand it to be fair to let know to each one that I am contacting the other one. Is it okay to add something like "For your information I have forwarded a similar request to Prof. X, since also his work aligns with my interests"?

Not sure it helps but I will need to be admitted to the graduate programme, it's not that individual professors have funds.